# DocumentDB Emulator browser issues

Tags: azure, emulation, microsoft-edge, azure-cosmosdb

I'm running Windows 10 - 1703 build 15063.296 - using Edge with Azure Cosmos DB Emulator, the UI tabs on the quick start page don't work? is anyone having the same issue?   BTW, the Azure portal works fine.

Comment: ``the UI tabs on the quick start page don't work?`` Do you mean that you could not browse https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html or you could not choose a platform and download the sample?

Answer (score 1):

> using Edge with Azure Cosmos DB Emulator, the UI tabs on the quick start page don't work?

If you mean that you could not choose other platforms except **.NET** in Quickstart page, you could try to uninstall and reinstall the Azure Cosmos DB Emulator, the issue seems fixed now.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that data explorer files got corrupted/non-functional.

After making sure you have the latest version of the emulator installed, follow these steps:

1. Exit the emulator

[image]

2. Delete all files under C:\Program Files\Azure Cosmos DB Emulator\Packages\DataExplorer\ (not the folder itself - just the files)
3. Open emulator

I hope this works for you! :)